# Connection Refused from Win10 to Samba on RPi with Arch

Tags: linux, windows, arch-linux, samba, raspberry-pi

I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Samba) to setup Samba on My Raspberry Pi running Arch.
My smb.conf is the following:

```
[global]
        server string = Samba Server
        workgroup = MYGROUP
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        max log size = 50
        printcap name = /etc/printcap
        name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host
        security = USER
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        browseable = No
        read only = No


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = No
        printable = Yes


[Test]
        comment = Test Folder
        path = /media/USB8GB/shares
        create mask = 0660
        directory mask = 0771
        force group = users
        read only = No
        valid users = @users
```

First of all, it does not show up in Windows 10. However, when trying to connect manually either to `\\ALARMPI\Test` or `\\192.168.1.4\Test`, it does recognize the server, but I can't login with the user I created. I get `connection refused`.
`smbclient -L ALARMPI` in SSH does work however.
I have numerous logfiles:

```
192.168.1.2.log  alarmpi.log  desktop-sf05bvt.log            fe80__ba27_xxxx_xxxx_ce6f.log  log.smbd  smbd.log
192.168.1.4.log  cores        fe80__8405_xxxx_xxxx_b470.log  log.nmbd                       nmbd.log
```

Only nmbd.log and smbd.log contain anything however.
nmbd.log:

```
[2017/04/03 00:53:57.475291,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:58(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2017/04/03 00:54:03.469717,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2017/04/03 00:54:53.502419,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****

  Samba name server ALARMPI is now a local master browser for workgroup MYGROUP on subnet 192.168.1.4

  *****
```

And several similiar lines like this before that from all the rebooting I did.
smbd.log

```
[2017/04/03 00:39:19.588558,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2017/04/03 00:39:19.673462,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:71(std_pcap_cache_reload)
  Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
[2017/04/03 00:52:12.043798,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:71(std_pcap_cache_reload)
  Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
[2017/04/03 00:54:06.779226,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2017/04/03 00:54:06.873653,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:71(std_pcap_cache_reload)
  Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
[2017/04/03 01:07:05.831166,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:71(std_pcap_cache_reload)
  Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
```

And again, several more lines like that.

It doesn't even say anything about my attempts at login from Windows.

I hope someone can help me with this problem, the googling I did only leaded me to problems that seemed unrelated and/or which solutions did not help.
If you need any additional info I'll be happy to provide you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to get this working while trying several things. The Arch wiki on Samba seems to omit some important information, just as the other tutorial did that I was using.

Make sure to enable a user after adding it to samba: `smbpasswd -L -e username`

Also make sure to add the user to the corresponding group if you specified said group in your share:
`usermod -a -G groupname username`

You should also make sure to set the right permissions on your shared folder, so that the group has permissions to it.

It's a good idea to set the `setgid` bit. In my case I set the group to `users` and the permission to `2770`.

Finally, I also changed my `[Test]` definition in smb.conf to the following:

```
[Test]
        comment = Test Folder
        path = /media/USB8GB/shares
        create mask = 0660
        directory mask = 2770
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 2770
        force group = users
        read only = No
        valid users = @users
```